# Prove that $2xe^x=1$ has a unique solution on $(0,1)$

Tags: continuity

Letting $f(x)=2xe^x-1$

$f(0)=-1<0$

$f(1)=2e-1>0$

So by the IVT there must be a solution in the interval $(0,1)$.
But I do not understand how I can show the uniqueness of a solution.

Comment: Please use Mathjax. Here's a quick [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Check the derivative of $f(x)=2xe^x-1$ on $[0,1]$ to see that $f$ is strictly increasing on that interval, which will allow you to conclude uniqueness (why?).

Comment: So f’(x)=2e^x+2xe^x=2e^x (1+x)=0
The derivative changes its sign at the point -1
That means f(x) is strictly increasing on that interval (0,1).
Strictly increasing functions have to be continuous.
But still do not understand how this will help us to prove uniqueness.

Comment: If $f(x)=f(y)=0$ for some $x,y\in[0,1]$, then by Rolle's theorem $\exists c\in(x,y)$ such that $f'(c)=0$. Can you see why this is a contradiction?

Comment: f is strictly increasing on the interval (0,1) that means there can’t be f(x)=f(y) for any x,y.

Comment: Exactly. So any solution has to be unique, otherwise you would have $f(x)=f(y)=0$ for two different $x,y$, which would contradict Rolle's theorem.

Comment: thank you very much!